# C++ use operator<< output as parameter in function

Tags: c++, boost, operator-keyword

I'm new to c++. I've seen a bazillion examples of the use of the `operator<<` where the output is sent to `cout` or `cerr`. Most classes overload this operator to have a human readable output in console, for instance [in this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}
```

It allows to do this:

```
Date dt(5, 6, 92);
cout << "The date is " << dt;
```

Now, I want to do the same thing, but I want to output to a file, not to a console. I'm using Boost, and I'm following [the example here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sources.html):

```
logging::record rec = lg.open_record();
if (rec)
{
    logging::record_ostream strm(rec);
    strm << "Hello, World!";
    strm.flush();
    lg.push_record(boost::move(rec));
}
```

The example is fine, but I want to put this code into a function. This is my code so far:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;

void log(severity_level level, std::string message)
{
    src::severity_logger<severity_level> lg;
    logging::record rec = lg.open_record(keywords::severity = level);
    if (rec)
    {
        logging::record_ostream strm(rec);
        strm << message;
        strm.flush();
        lg.push_record(boost::move(rec));
    }
}
```

Of course this works for `string`, but it won't work with the `Date` from the example above:

```
Date dt(5, 6, 92);
log(severity_level::info, "The date is "); // No problem here
log(severity_level::info, dt); // Error, dt is not of type string
```

How can I do something like that?

Comment: *" it won't work with the `Date` example above"* - Why not? Does `logging::record_ostream` not derive from `std::ostream&`? Otherwise I don't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't work

Comment: You tagged [tag:boost], so I suppose `logging::record_ostream` is from boost? You'd likely need another overload to accept boost streams.

Comment: @UnholySheep because I'm logging `message`, that I pass as a string parameter, in the last piece of code. Sorry if the question was unclear, I'll edit.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it is `namespace logging = boost::log;`, [as defined here in the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/how_to_read.html); fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To support multiple types, make `log()` a template function. Problem with your original code is that you only overloaded `operator<<`, and you have not overloaded any [conversion operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

```
template<typename T>
void log(severity_level level, const T& message)
{
    // ...
    strm << message;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working for me. It's compiling, but then I get an error "undefined reference to [function]" with the .o file, as if the linker can't find the template function.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what I am supposed to do with conversion operators in my case...

Comment: @ocramot If you want to implicitly convert `Date` to `std::string`, create `operator std::string()` for it.